# Nginx rewrite regex with port change

Tags: spring, tomcat, nginx, netflix-zuul

My web stack is composed of (nginx (port: 29090) -> tomcat)
nginx act as reverse proxy, and tomcat host 2 webapps
1. For Authentication (using netflix zuul ) - running on port 29091 
2. SensorThings API server - running on port 29101 

This below request is passed using zuul.route.sensor.url=http://localhost:29090/sensor-internal

Below is nginx.conf block

```
location /sensor-internal/ {
        include cors_support;            
        rewrite ^(/sensor/)(.*)$ SensorThingsServer-1.0/v1.0/$2 break;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        rewrite_log on;

    }
```

I want to replace the URL 
 http://localhost:29090/sensor/xxxx(n)/yyyy(m) 
to
 http://localhost:29101/SensorThingsServer-1.0/v1.0/xxxx(n)/yyyy(m)

See change in port and replace sensor with STS-1.0/v1.0/
I believe the above block will not work for port change. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

You should describe separate location `/sensor/` and perform rewriting there, because location `/sensor-internal/` you have defined does not serve `/sensor/*` request.

```
location /sensor/ {
   rewrite ^/(/sensor/)(.*)$ http://localhost:29101/SensorThingsServer-1.0/v1.0/$2 break;
   rewrite_log on;
}
```

Comment: you can move rewrite outside block and block wont be needed

Comment: technically - yes, you can move it into `server` context. But in this case that rule will be testing for every request to this server - which result in extra useless, from my point of view, CPU usage. When you define a `location` - you clearly specify what URIs shoult be validated against this rewrite rule.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the thought process. Will keep that in mind :-)

Comment: is the ":" a mistake in your answer i.e. should localhost:29101:SensorThingsServer-1.0/ be localhost:29101/SensorThingsServer-1.0/ ?

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewT ! Fixed it - hope this typo didn't interfere my idea understanding.